# Timeout error on removing node from AWS redis cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster

Whenever a node(read relpica in a shard) is removed/added to AWS redis cluster, redis-py-cluster doesn't refresh node ips on its own resulting in:

1. In case of adding a node, the traffic never reads/writes to the new node
2. In case of removing a node, the traffic keeps going to the node removed, giving timeout error as shown below:

````
ConnectionErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 510, in connectsock = self._connect()
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 567, in _connectraise err
File "/home/ubuntu/app/dealsenv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 555, in _connectsock.connect(socket_address)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rediscluster/client.py", line 630, in _execute_commandconnection.send_command(*args)
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 657, in send_commandself.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args),
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 629, in send_packed_commandself.connect()
File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 515, in connectraise 
ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to 172.xx.xx.xx:6379. Connection timed out.```
````

Both these observations were made after the cluster is in available state.

Once containers are relaunched, the issue goes away for both the above cases.

Cluster mode is enabled in AWS redis cluster.
Library used to form connection to the cluster: redis-py-cluster==2.1.3
Connection config: {"read_from_replicas": True, "skip_full_coverage_check": True}

Does anyone know how to make the client refresh the node IPs immediately with minimum to no time?